# setting server_default in sqlalchemy fails

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

this is the stuff that I want SQLAlchemy to do:

```
blesk_dev=# alter table address add column reg_at timestamp without time zone default (now() at time zone 'utc');
ALTER TABLE
```

that is, I want to set a default UTC time for a column. In pure psql, as seen above, this succeeds.

This is what it's supposed to look like in SQLAlchemy code:

```
reg_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default="(now() at time zone 'utc')")
```

But when I try to migrate I get this:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.ProgrammingError: (ProgrammingError) syntax error at or near "utc"
LINE 1: ...STAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT '(now() at time zone 'utc')'
                                                                 ^
 "ALTER TABLE address ADD COLUMN reg_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT '(now() at time zone 'utc')'" {}
```

So there's an issue with single/double quotes I presume.

I tried

```
"(now() at time zone \'utc\')"
```

but this gets me the same error.

I then swapped the quotes:

```
'(now() at time zone "utc")'
'(now() at time zone \"utc\")'
```

to no avail:

```
sqlalchemy.exc.DataError: (DataError) invalid input syntax for type timestamp: "(now() at time zone "utc")"
 'ALTER TABLE address ADD COLUMN reg_at TIMESTAMP WITHOUT TIME ZONE DEFAULT \'(now() at time zone "utc")\''
```

How do I work around this?

Answer (score 8):

Consider using the `text` function of sqlalchemy:

```
from sqlalchemy import text
reg_at = db.Column(db.DateTime, server_default=text('(now() at time zone "utc")'))
```

Comment: text('(now() at time zone "utc")')) - does this work with postgres? I dont believe so. Error creating tables: (psycopg2.errors.FeatureNotSupported) cannot use column reference in DEFAULT expression
LINE 6: ...ESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE DEFAULT (now() at time zone "utc") NOT